# building form dynamically with jquery

Tags: jquery

I've got a form that I build when you click an edit button in the table.  See the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/UtNaa/42/

The problem is that it is not showing the right form.  If it is AXIS:

```
if (cameratype == "AXIS")
```

it builds a form with 8 fields, otherwise it builds a form with 5 fields.  To see this behavior best, go to the fiddle and click the first row "Edit" button.  See the form it builds, it has 5 fields.  Now click the next "Edit" button for the next cameratype.  It shows the same 5 fields, when it should show 8 fields.

But if you refresh your browser on that fiddle and click the second "Edit" button in the table this time, you can see that it does show 8 fields.  But again if you click on "Edit" for the first row it is also 8 instead of 5 fields.

So if you click cameratype=WEBCAM it should show 5 fields and when you click cameratype=AXIS it should show the 8 fields.  Note that there are common fields between the two.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if (mydiv.find("form").length) {
```

Is giving you the problems. Essentially, it's just showing you the same form you've first created. You need to remove the form on `cancel`/`apply`, or try to detect if the correct type of form is available and select/show that one.

Working example using `$.empty()`: http://jsfiddle.net/UtNaa/44/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
if (mydiv.find("form").length) {
   mydiv.show(); 
}
```

After the first time you hit the "Edit" button, the form is populated, and the dynamic controls are not regenerated since it just calls `mydiv.show`.